# How to get the deleted array element from the array after using the .splice method

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

I deleted an array element using the splice method and it worked just like the way I wanted.
Now I need the particular array element that was deleted in the splice method too . How do I do that?

Comment: Pls provide an example

Comment: `splice` method return deleted item from array

Comment: let currentList= this.state.todoItems;
    currentList.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({
      todoItems:currentList
    })                                      this method deleted the particular array element and returned the array back just like the way i wanted. I also want to get the element that was deleted seperatly. How do I do that?

Comment: do you want to monitor changes ? Like: detect when an item is removed?

Comment: I am a beginner and was building a todo app . When delete button is clicked , particular entry is deleted. When the button task completed is clicked I want the particular array element to get deleted, as well as , I want that deleted array element for further use. I used splice method to delete the array element and now I want that deleted array element too for further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

//removes 4th index element
var x = arr.splice(4, 1);
//splice(index,no of elements)

//console:4th index:[ 5 ]
console.log(x);


console.log(arr);
//console:[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
//not 4th element
```

Answer (score 0):

splice returns the deleted element and you can save it into a varital:

```
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "June"];
var x = months.splice(4, 1, 'May');
// replaces 1 element at index 4
console.log(x);
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ["June"]Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May"],
```